Energy distribution of water molecules without considering the free gas hypothesis
considering water molecules as a free gas at a certain temperature, their kinetic energy distribution is given by the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution (associated with temperature), right? So, if I want to assign a kinetic energy to a molecule in the gas according to the distribution, I just need to sample an energy from it.
However, moving to a more realistic scenario where we don't consider the assumption of free gas, is there any distribution that allows sampling a probable energy including the rotational and vibrational motions of the water molecule?
Secondly, I'm not sure if there's a direct connection, but I've come across some things related to a frequency spectrum which is sometimes called phonon density of states. For example, for light water, we would have the following distribution, which includes diffusion, rotation, and vibrational modes of the water molecules.

Is there any link between these concepts? In other words, does the above distribution
describes in some way the energy distribution associated with the water molecules, considering all translational, vibrational, and rotational movements, or it has nothing to do with it?
Thanks in advance!

Are you aware of the equipartition theorem? If you want to model the typical energies in the gas phase, this might be a good starting place.
